# Windows Application Icon Files

Tags: .net, windows, icons

when creating an .exe on Windows (XP - 7, assuming it's the same process), what is the format for the application icon?  what is the file extension?  what size is the maximum?

with applications on Mac OS X, it is possible to right-click on the application and select "Show Package Contents".  from here, an .icns file can be found in a folder called "resources" along with other assets pertaining to the application.  .icns files contain 5 sizes of the same icon file (16x16, 32x32, 128x128, 256x256 and 512x512).  an application from XCode developer tools called "Icon Composer" is used to produce .icns files

i have zero experience with Windows software development but would like to know best practices for preparing icon files for Windows applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com/) to display the resources in any .exe file

> Resource Tuner lets anyone view, edit, extract, and replace strings, bitmaps, logos and icons... All that make up the visual part of your Windows program.

Comment: Just because an answer points to a commercial product doesn't mean it's SPAM or a non-answer. This is not self promotional, it obviously helped the OP and was offered in the spirit of being helpful. Kindly, hold the flags.

Comment: @Tim: The OP marking it as answer does not make it a proper answer either. The reason for SO's rules regarding answers are clearly there, so that not only the OP benefits from the answer, but people - just like me - having similar questions. The OP clearly did NOT ask: "What tool can I use to analyze application icons of a windows application?" A SO answer which is more in the spirit of SO and actually answering some of the questions of the OP can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3244679 So people, please do NOT hold the flags.

Answer (score 1):

visual Studio has tools for editing and embedding an icon on an executable file, at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You need an .ico file; more info [Creating Windows XP Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx)

Comment: this site states that Windows icons max at 48 pixels x 48 pixels.  is that true?

Comment: maybe in XP.. I know that in Vista and 7 your max size can be 256x256 (compressed png).