# Blurry desktop icon using ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I'm deploying a WPF application using ClickOnce and the desktop icon is blurry. Does anybody have any information on how to fix this? The .ico is 32x32.

Image of icons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHD45.png

Original .ico file on the top left, right of that is the desktop shortcut created by ClickOnce, below that shows the titlebar, and on the bottom is the taskbar icon.

Edit: Okay, so first let me inform you, the original icon was not the correct dimensions and apparently just editing the .ico doesn't fix that for the solution. When I removed the .ico from the solution and added it back the quality improved slightly. I think the improvement wasn't as great as I'd hoped due to the lack of anti-aliasing on the icon? I'm not quite sure if this is possible, and I'm sorry for my ignorance as this isn't my strong suit, but is it possible to add anti-aliasing to the .ico on deployment?

Here is the image of the updated image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRiFR.png

Also, if this isn't possible is there maybe a technique in the creation of an icon that makes them look smoother?

Comment: May I suggest that you get a nice 256x256 version of your original icon in .png format and then use an icon converter e.g http://convertico.com/ Then you have multiple icon sizes in the same .ico file and windows will choose the best instead of resizing. Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx

Comment: Also I think the answer here says you need 256x256 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236115/which-icon-sizes-should-my-windows-applications-icon-include

Comment: It does appear that having an icon at 256x256 does the trick. Thanks so much. I was trying to use clickonce as a keyword in my searches because I figured it had something to do with it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DaveWilliams Your answer was correct. If you could please submit the answer, which I will then accept as the valid answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest that you get a nice 256x256 version of your original icon in .png format and then use an icon converter e.g http://convertico.com/ Then you have multiple icon sizes in the same .ico file and windows will choose the best instead of resizing.

Also see:

[Microsoft on icon sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236115/which-icon-sizes-should-my-windows-applications-icon-include)

Comment: Method still works great! (Using Visual Studio 2019)