# Taskbar icon looks pixelated using ClickOnce

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, clickonce, taskbar

When I run my wpf application in debug mode, the icon on the taskbar looks fine (left image), but after I published and open the application, the icon looks pixelated (right image).

[image]

I've referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269425/blurry-desktop-icon-using-clickonce) and I set the icon image to 256x256, but still looks pixelated.

Please help.

Comment: is the image in .png format??

Comment: Hi @Akansha, is in .ico format

Comment: what was the size  of your original image before converting it to 256x256?

Comment: 200x210 in png format

Comment: That what is creating problem. The image looks pix-elated  as the size of original image was small. Try with some other image which has resolution equal to or higher than 256x256 and then convert that.png to .ico format.

Answer (score 0):

try using an ico editor to save the icon with all the correct resolutions (the OS will display the correct one). I use icofx, but there are many options if you google it - they should all correct your image proportions. Most should have an equivalent option to the 'save windows icon' (in icofx) where you select all the resolutions you want to add to the file.

---

Just another thought - is you icon a resource file? If so you may need to remove it then add it again and make sure the resource is set to publish correctly (so you are not using an old version).