# C# Application Shortcut Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, icons, installation

I have a problem with the Setup of a C# application. Happens I have added an icon to the application (under project settings, on the form itself and on the shortcuts inside the setup), but the Icons do not appear on the shortcut I create on the desktop and Start Menu!

I have had this problem more than once, it appears to have something to do with Windows  7 and the resolution of the .ico file. I have solved it many times in the past trough trying (changing the resolution of the icon), but somehow this time it will not work.

Furthermore: If I use the wrong resolution (too high for example), the application won't start. Specially on Windows XP.

I hope you can help me. What resolution should I use? What is standard?

Comment: if by setup you mean installation, which installer creation tech do you use?

Comment: I use VS2008 and use the MSI Installer standard there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, ico-file should contain several icons. You assign icon in the project properties, by setting Icon in Application category. Windows will choose most appropriate icon (when creating icon on desktop, to example).

You will surely need icon editor. I am using *Greenfish Icon Editor Pro*. It's free and seems cool.

Then you need to know about sizes, but it's very easy to find (also GFIE warns when you create icon which will be only valid for Vista or higher), to example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3236115/1997232).

Comment: Thanks. I tried Greenfish Icon Editor Pro and it really works nice :) Maybe the Icon File was missing some resolutions. I will try it with XP later.

Comment: It is weird to see a free software with a "Pro" tag though

Comment: That's what I was also thinking haha better I will read the T&C's

Answer (score 0):

put your icon in the same folder where you have your .xml, .c, .. files
after that, on each window, add this property :

```
Icon='../iconName.ico'
```

you can place your icon at an other folder but make sur than your icon is into your project.
but be carefull, because an icon file have 2 icons. 
one which have 32x32 size and an other which have 16x16.
one is for taskbar and the other is for topleft corner of the window...

Comment: I am working with .NET Framework 3.5 and Winforms on Visual Studio 2008. How would I do that here?

Comment: open your icon file with visual studio and edit it with
you will have correct icon file for your .Net framework.

Comment: after that, put your icon into your project if it you haven't do it.
then in each winows, add into `<Window ... ... ` this property `Icon=""` and to be sure, drag your icon file from your projet tree files and drop it between the two ". it will create automatically the path

Comment: I think you can only do that in XAML based applications. Or am I wrong?

Comment: C# files. On Windows Forms it's all C#. The problem must be the icon itself. I have added dozens of them already to other applications, it just doesn't work on this one.

Comment: The icon is set in the project properties page. To open it right click on the project name in the solution explorer. in the page that opens, there is an Application tab, in this tab you can set the icon.