# Visual studio - Make your program have big icon on desktop when installed

Tags: visual-studio, icons, ico

So I know this title sounds weird , but hear me out!

So...
I have set the icon for my app. It was a really big (like 128x128) icon. But when I release it and install it it only has a small icon.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diy7x.jpg - my ico

But I want it to be big like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwhQS.jpg - spotify ico

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Windows is likely ignoring your pretty 128px icon and falling back to an upscaled lower-quality one.

I've followed the advice of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236115/which-icon-sizes-should-my-windows-applications-icon-include) in the past, and it's resolved this kind of issue for me. Essentially, the 48px and 256px images are the most important components.

You could also try reverse-engineering the header of your Spotify icon to see how they do it. The ICO format is [well documented on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)).