# Desktop icon scale to fit when zoomed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem where my icon doesn't scale to fit when I zoom in on it when it's on my desktop.

[image]

Followed by when I zoom in.
[image]

How can I make sure the image for my program scales as well?

It does scale down, but it stops scaling up after it gets to its default size.

I'm using Visual Studio and my software is done in C# WPF.

Comment: Try using a .svg file instead of .ico file

Comment: Can you link your Icon?

Comment: @VishalPrajapati An SVG as an application/file icon? How would you do that?

Comment: You aren't following [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3236115/1997232)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with code. Your `*.ico` File is missing the supported images.

The `*.ico` icons can have different images for multiple sizes, eg. 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128, 256x256.

There is [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/491180/how-do-i-embed-multiple-sizes-in-an-ico-file) how to embed them.

Comment: Hey, I followed the instructions but it still didn't work. My new *.ico file contains all the different sizes but it still acts the same way.

Comment: @AlWooz Did you refresh the Windows Internal Icon cache? https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting

Comment: My mistake, seemed to be an issue why my setup-project where it didnt put the new icon inside the wizard, it kept using the old one.