# How to package several icons for different sizes in a VS C++ app?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, icons, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing a C++ app in Visual Studio 2022 with a UI (UI library is wxWidgets). I'm trying to figure out how icons work. I gathered from researching that Windows expects a variety of different icons to be packaged with apps for the best UX (see [Which icon sizes should my Windows application's icon include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236115/which-icon-sizes-should-my-windows-applications-icon-include)). However I can't seem to find a way to get multiple icons taken into account.

My understanding so far is that all resource related things, including icons, are controlled by `Resource.h` and `<projectName>.rc`, both of which are initially provided by the VS template for a C++ App.

I've removed the provided icons (i.e the "normal" and "small" ones) and have instead imported many icons, one for each size, in the Resource View.

[image: Resource View]

But regardless of that, always one icon seem to be used at a time.

Checking the contents of `<projectName>.rc`, I see the following:

[image: .rc excerpt]

I also expect the following, in `Resource.h`, to be relevant:

[image: Resource.h excerpt]

It seems that independently of the icon sizes, `IDI_ICON1` is used. If it's 16x16, it's upscaled in context that requires it, if it's 256x256, it's downscaled (poorly, somehow ?) when required i.e in almost all contexts.

How should this be done ? Are there resources available on the matter I may have missed ?

Comment: Did you try to embed several icons with different resolution into one ICO file?

Comment: ... Oh. So that's how .ico works... Thanks @DmytroOvdiienko

Comment: If it works, I can convert the comment into solution so it does not lose in time

Comment: Go ahead, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should embed all your ico files with different resolution into one ico file. The ico file is actually a container and can contain multiple images inside.