# How to make a shortcut to Java desktop application?

Tags: java, icons, shortcut-file

I have made a desktop application in Java (using JDBC and Swing) using Eclipse.
I want to make a shortcut to this application (an icon).  When the icon is double clicked, the application will run.

How to do it?

Comment: Would an Exectutable JAR do the trick for you ?

Comment: That would depend on the platform you want to deploy on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the shortcut/icon execute your application:

```
java -jar yourApplication.jar org.example.your.MainClass
```

Comment: I am doing it first time..  Will u please elaborate, how to do ?

Answer (score 4):

Deploy the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Not only does it have a simple system for installing desk-top and menu item shortcuts (on supported OS) for an app. *with icons,* but also offers the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html) that allows the shortcuts to be examined/installed programmatically.

For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323510/how-to-run-java-programs-by-clicking-on-their-icon-on-windows/11323662#11323662).  The 2 icons on the right hand side (JotPad & StarZoom) were installed by JWS.

[image]

Comment: Well integrated on Mac OS X, too.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web application - Go to Desktop + Right Click + Select New Option + Select Shortcut option + Specify your path in the location field + Click Next + Type the shortcut name + Finish.

So, now you can view your application as a desktop shortcut and if you click on it, it will automatically load your web application on one click. Then you can change the Shortcut Icons in properties.

Thank you.

Comment: What OS is this for?