# some good .jar to .exe converters?

Tags: java, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

i am learning java, i am a total beginner though i have learnt some python before. for some people who know what python is, it is totally a pain in the ass situation to compile it. i used a 3rd party software cx_freeze to do so but all the code wouldn't get compiled.

though python compiling isn't the aim of this question. what i want to do is to convert .jar to .exe. now i know that there are some solutions available. but which one is the best in terms of compatibility? what i mean to say is that can i import a huge amount of modules and still get it to work? can i have advance projects compiled?

also, is there a software that has a gui to do this? because i had to completely manually do the compiling in python.

also, is there a way of converting .class to .exe without converting it to .jar

thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to test different solutions to find something that really works for you.

According to my (limited) experience, [`Spoon Studio`](http://spoon.net/) is easy to use and provides good compatibility.

There are also other solutions; take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2011746/303270) answer.