# How to Create a exe file devolop for Java application by Using Netbeans and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, netbeans, exe

I want to Create .exe File for devolop for Java application by Using  Netbeans and MySQL , I know to Create but I have Problem with MySql , How do i put My Sql Data base to .exe file Please Help me

Answer (score 1):

If you develop a Java application, the standard is to create a .jar not a .exe. If you want to create a platform dependent .exe either use another language like C++, or look into tools like explained in the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe).

Answer (score 0):

As I know, MySQL doesn't support embedded problems. You have to run it as a independent component of your system.

If your really need the DB come along with your application, you can try SQLite https://sqlite.org/ or BekelyDB.

For more information, take a look at this to have more detail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

Hope this help.