# A way to wrap a java application

Tags: java, maven, powershell, exe

I have developed a game in Java language. I'd like to make a pretty installer.
None of those I've tried worked properly.
The build process is made with Maven.
For now I launch the application with a batch file. I want an icon on a executable. Today I tried PS2EXE but I don't know Powershell. I also tried BAT2EXE but the executable crashed several times.
The project is free software, so I can distribute the source but also want a more end-user zip or setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this solution to make the java program run as an executable.

[Compiling a java program into an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe)

You can then use a open source Windows installer program to easily install it.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

http://www.innosetup.com/isinfo.php

http://wixedit.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know about converting Java programs to EXE files and then some: *[Convert Java to EXE — Why, When, When Not and How](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html)*.

Just short descriptions of all the available tools, with URLs: *[Best JAR to EXE Conversion Tools, Free and Commercial](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/best-jar-to-exe-conversion-tools-free-commercial.html)*.

I am the author and maintainer of both resources.