# How to create executable .exe file from .jar file?

Tags: java

I've created an app using netbeans IDE but it is in .jar format.How do I convert it into .exe to use on individual system ?

Answer (score 1):

many responses here:
[Compiling a java program into an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe)

JSmooth .exe wrapper

JarToExe 1.8

Executor

Advanced Installer [for Java](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html)  - tutorial [for Java applications](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html)

GCJ

Launch4J: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Your link indicates this question should probably be flagged as a duplicate rather than answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just create a runnable file of your application, the JAR should be enough to do the job. You can export it as an executable jar with the manifest file and run it just by double cliking it.

Still if you require an exe, then you can use `Launch4J`. To create an exe,  create `jar` file for your application using your IDE with proper `MANIFEST` file packaged inside. Then launch `Launch4J` and select your jar file and you should be able to create an exe easily.

For more details, take a look at this [link here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use launch4j this can make jar an exe