# Compiling/packaging java programs into standalone executables?

Tags: java, deployment, portable-executable

I would like to deploy a java (or javafx program) which is usable even on a system that **doesn't have JRE**.

This question has been asked and answered:

- [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)
- [Compiling a java program into an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-executable)

But those 2 questions are over 10 years old, and I'm wondering if there are any new/better options as of 2022.

Comment: java has no native implementation for compiling as executable on any system. you should try .NET which support bytecode compilation

Comment: Yes, since Java 9, you can build installers with no 3rd party tools: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9. Just to clarify, this does *not* compile to a native executable, but simply ports an installer with dedicated vm packaged as part of the installed app. It's no longer possible to make native binaries from Java. It *was* briefly, as part of the Gnu Classpath project, but that's gone now

Answer (score 0):

There are some options you could choose from:

1. Bundle your JRE in your package

> Eclipse does this for example. The put a JRE in the downloaded ZIP-File

2. The rise of the native images

> Some projects start to do native java-executables. One is [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/). But the don't support JavaFx. Base technology for that is [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/)

Spring is also starting native images: [Spring-Native](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Here is an example of a java-fx native image: [Java-FX Native Demo](https://github.com/Wooyme/jfx-native-image-demo)

Answer (score 0):

The tools to compile a JavaFX program into a native exectable can be found here: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin

Depending on your needs it might be also interesting though to just package your program for each platform via jpackage. Maybe following this tutorial https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX