# How Can I convert Java To Exe

Tags: java, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiling a java program into an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe)

Hi,
I'd like to convert my java application to exe file which is not depends on a pre installed JRE file.
Which tool can do so? I prefer to converty my application to a real exex file.
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The beauty of java is that it is platform independent. So, **converting it to a platform-dependent executable is a great sin: it kills the very purpose of java!**

But if you're okay with that, use some thirdparty software.

**Commercial:**

- [JEXECreator](http://www.ucware.com/jexec/)
- [exe4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html)
- [NativeJ](http://www.dobysoft.com/products/nativej/)
- [execJava](http://www.javaapis.com/execjava/)
- [Executor](http://mpowers.net/executor/)
- [JExePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/)
- [Jlaunch](http://www.magi-au.com/download/)

**Free:**

- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
- [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [jstart32](http://jstart32.sourceforge.net/)
- [exeJ](http://www.sureshotsoftware.com/exej/)
- [Janel](http://janel.sourceforge.net/janel/index.html)
- [jstart](http://www.objects.com.au/products/jstart/index.jsp)
- [Roxes Ant Tasks](http://www.roxes.com/produkte/rat.html)
- [Marner Java Launcher](http://www.rolemaker.dk/nonRoleMaker/javalauncher/marner_java_launcher.htm)
- [jelude](http://www.sfu.ca/~tyuen/jelude/)

More similar discussions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516399/create-exe-for-java-program), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309329/best-free-tool-to-build-an-exe-from-java-code), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) and even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743029/how-to-get-executable-file-of-java-programm).

Comment: Are you saying that Java doesn't have any other purpose than being platform-independent? Because if Java turns out to have some other useful property, then maybe using it for a platform-dependent solution wouldn't be as great of a sin?

Comment: Exactly.  Java is a programming language, and platform-specific development is not a sin per se.  Not even in a programming language that is platform independent.