# Making an executable with most Java code, but maybe another language added in

Tags: java, c++, exe, dmg

I have been looking everywhere, and being a novice at Java and lacking proper terminology it seems impossible to find this.
I assume the correct term is "wrapping", but looking at other Java applications, such as: Minecraft, and seeing how pretty the launcher is and custom buttons, it seems impossible to accomplish such a feat with JFrame.
Do they code their own sort of frame? I've heard that you can "wrap" Java code in like C++ to make the launcher, and after passing the screen is launches the game (minecraft.jar).
Also, how is the exe file created? That once it is run it checks for a patch from the server, that installs the necessary files in a given directory and checks there for save files?
Is it another language? if so which? Which do You recommend? A resource for learning all of this?
These are the main aspects that I've been struggling to learn as no one seems to ask a similar question as I.

Also, considering Java is cross-platform, my main targets are Windows > Mac, for now I can't be bothered to worry about Linux considering I'm already struggling so much here; so for now, how to create a Exe file, if need be, in C++ or any other language, then perhaps DMG for Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of things to consider.  I would suggest that *for now* you use Java WebStart to launch your application.  This gives you things like:

- Easy distribution - put files on a web server somewhere and a JNLP file describing how to glue your files together.
- No messing with EXE-wrappers and multiple distributions - this is in the standard Java installation.
- Easy updates - just create a new set of files (don't update jars in place) and a new JNLP and thats it.
- A sandbox without any effort.  Full access to the machine needs code signing which these days is a moving target.  Sandbox should be enough for quite a bit though.

Then when you find you have enough users to warrant platform-specific distributions, you can add these as needed instead of getting everything working up front, where you should be concentrating on your application instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to go the JNLP route, there a number of tools which can do what you ask for.. my favorite is [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net), which is easy to use via the launch4j-maven-plugin, see e.g. this [launch4j-demo](https://github.com/vorburger/launch4j-demo) illustrating how to use it.

PS: Alternatives include http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmooth/ or http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html (.com). Note that similar Qs to this with more have been asked on [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file?lq=1), [How Can I convert Java To Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855937/how-can-i-convert-java-to-exe?rq=1), [Best free tool to build an exe from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309329/best-free-tool-to-build-an-exe-from-java-code?rq=1)

Comment: the thing is I don't like third party tools, I'd rather customize it, I understand that there are things like that, but I'd rather customize it to my needs even if I had to code it myself, just wanted to be pointed in the right direction (like which language to use) how to go about it, so I could get started, but I appreciate the input!